# Given a continuous function f on $[a,b]$ such that $f([a,b])\subset [a,b]$, why does there exist an $x: g(x) \lt 0$ for $g(x)=f(x)-x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I'm trying to prove that for a function that is continuous on $[a,b]$, with $f([a,b] \subset [a,b]$ there exists a $c \in [a,b]: f(c)=c$. If you consider a function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ the result would follow from the intermediate value theorem once you know that there exists a value for which $g(x)$ is negative, so my question is why is there definitely such a value if you know that the image of a function is a subset of the domain?

Comment: You know $g(a) \geq a - a = 0$ and $g(b) \leq b-b = 0$. If equality holds, you are done. So suppose not.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: I don't think it's true, boywholived gives an easy counterexample for any interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: This is only true if the image is a strict subset of the domain (or if you write $g(x)\le 0$ instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that there exists a $c$ such that $f(c)=c$:

**Case I:** If $g(x)>0$ for all $x$, then $f(b)>b$(a contradiction).

**Case II:** If $g(x)<0$ for all $x$, then $f(a)<a$(a contradiction).

**Case III:**  If $g(x)>0$ for some values of $x$ and $g(x)<0$ for some other values, use intermediate value theorem.

**Case IV:**  If $g(x)=0$ for all $x$, there is nothing to prove.